# Looking for best way to execute Yes/No Query check in select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was wondering if anyone could recommend the best way to execute this. I will introduce you to what I'm working on. 
I've written a select query with some sub-queries which gets order records, I have a number business logic that these orders need to meet so that they come up on the report.

Additionally I've added a **nested case statement** which helps me determine is the business logic is met and it simply returns a Yes or a No. So far all looks great! 
E.G.
[image]

Above is just a sample result for one order (29817). What I need to do next is only show Order_No when NOYESCHECK returns all YES's. 
Nested Case statement:

```
(case when sm.supply_code='Project Inventory' and 
  (select po.order_no 
        from purchase_order_line_all po 
        where po.contract = sm.contract
        and po.part_no = sm.part_no
        and po.activity_seq = sm.activity_seq 
        and po.project_id = sm.project_id
        and po.state in ('Closed','Arrived','Recieved') order by po.date_entered desc fetch first 1 row only) is not null then 'YES' 
  when sm.supply_code='Invent Order' and
        ( select sum(QTY_ONHAND - QTY_RESERVED)
        from inventory_part_in_stock ipis 
        where ipis.contract = sm.contract
        and ipis.part_no = sm.part_no
        and ipis.QTY_ONHAND - ipis.QTY_RESERVED > '0'
        and ipis.project_id  is null 
        and ipis.AVAILABILITY_CONTROL_ID not in ('QUARANTINE','RD','TRANSIT','PRE SCRAP')
        ) is not null then 'YES'

  else 'NO' end)NoYesCheck
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?  I have tried using ALL operator but it didn't work quite as expected. What I tried with ALL operator:

```
and 'YES' = ALL (case when sm.supply_code='Project Inventory' and 
  (select po.order_no 
        from purchase_order_line_all po 
        where po.contract = sm.contract
        and po.part_no = sm.part_no
        and po.activity_seq = sm.activity_seq 
        and po.project_id = sm.project_id
        and po.state in ('Closed','Arrived','Recieved') order by po.date_entered desc fetch first 1 row only) is not null then 'YES' 
  when sm.supply_code='Invent Order' and
        ( select sum(QTY_ONHAND - QTY_RESERVED)
        from inventory_part_in_stock ipis 
        where ipis.contract = sm.contract
        and ipis.part_no = sm.part_no
        and ipis.QTY_ONHAND - ipis.QTY_RESERVED > '0'
        and ipis.AVAILABILITY_CONTROL_ID not in ('QUARANTINE','RD','TRANSIT','PRE SCRAP')
        and ipis.project_id  is null 
        ) is not null then 'YES'

  else 'NO' end)
```

It seemed to return only lines with 'YES' in my check but the purpose here is:
If check is done per order and returns at least one 'No' then do not show the order. So in above image this order was never meant to show up as a result in my query but it did. So I'm a little stuck.

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if I need to provide more info.

Thanks,
Kasia

Comment: Hi Kasia, please include a query, some minimal table structure and expected results so that we can help you. More info is [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: @wolφi is this sufficient or more is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your `NOYESCHECK` column in a subselect within the where clause combined with a NOT IN check.

Psuedo code:

```
select
  --main query columns
from data_source
where key_column not in (
  select distinct 
    key_column
  from (
    select
      key_column,
      noyescheck_column
    from data_source
    where noyescheck_column = 'NO'
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this help? See comments within code.

```
SQL> with
  2  -- this is what your query currently returns
  3  test (order_no, component_part, noyescheck) as
  4    (select 29817, 100, 'NO'  from dual union all
  5     select 29817, 101, 'YES' from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select 30000, 200, 'YES' from dual union all
  8     select 30000, 201, 'YES' from dual union all
  9     --
 10     select 40000, 300, 'NO'  from dual
 11    ),
 12  -- find ORDER_NOs whose NOYESCHECK = YES only
 13  yess as
 14    (select order_no
 15     from test
 16     group by order_no
 17     having min(noyescheck) = max(noyescheck)
 18        and min(noyescheck) = 'YES'
 19    )
 20  -- return only ORDER_NOs that satisfy condition
 21  select t.*
 22  from test t join yess y on y.order_no = t.order_no;

  ORDER_NO COMPONENT_PART NOY
---------- -------------- ---
     30000            200 YES
     30000            201 YES

SQL>
```

Comment: Hey @Littlefoot thanks for this going to try this now!